# OAuth2 + Generate New Authorization Bearer Access Token C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

Could any one help me out to Generate Access Token in C# MVC.

[PostMan Access Token Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV2Q0.jpg)

**Below Code Works fine in Console Application But its not working in MVC c# am getting Error as "URL Could not be Resolved"**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)  {
       Console.WriteLine("Starting ...");
        DoIt().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 private static async Task<string> DoIt()     {

        accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

return accessToken;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

            // We want the response to be JSON.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Build up the data to POST.
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "clientId"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "clientSecret"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_token_url", "Access Token URL"));

            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

            // Post to the Server and parse the response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("Token", content).Result;
            string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

            // return the Access Token.
            return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
        }
    }
```

Comment: **client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);**                                                    // Here what is the value of baseUrl?? I think it's remain same that's why URL conflict issue arises.

Comment: did you debug it to see what URL is being generated? What's `baseURL` - you haven't shown us how you create that.

Comment: we have Declared baseUrl as a Static Value like below

Baseurl = https://preview.com/connect/authorize

and

Access Token Url ilike https://preview/connect/Token